# Python Ripple carry Adder?

Tags: python

I'm currently doing a project in my Discrete Mathematics class and we have to code:

1.) *RippleCarryAdder*: it is a circuit for adding fixed-size, 5-bit integers. Parameters:

```
x_array: operand 1, i.e. an array of 5 wires
y_array: operand 2, i.e. an array of 5 wires
s_array: sum, i.e. an array of 6 wires
```

2.) *RippleCarryAdder*: it is a circuit for adding n-bit integers. Parameters:

```
x_array: operand 1, i.e. an array of n wires
y_array: operand 2, i.e. an array of n wires
s_array: sum, i.e. an array of (n+1) wires
```

**I have already coded the half and full adder.**

I understand the basic concept of the Ripple Carry. I'm just having a hard time putting it down in code. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import unittest
from digital_circuit_core import *

class InputLengthException( Exception ): pass

class MyPrettySimulator( Simulator ):

def HalfAdder(self, a, b, s, c):
    # internal wires
    d = self.Wire('d-wire')
    e = self.Wire('e-wire')

    self.OrGate(a, b, d)
    self.AndGate(a, b, c)
    self.Inverter(c, e)
    self.AndGate(d, e, s)

    return 'ok'


def FullAdder(self, a, b, c_in, s, c_out):
    # internal wires
    d = self.Wire()
    c1 = self.Wire()
    c2 = self.Wire()

    self.HalfAdder(b, c_in, d, c1)
    self.HalfAdder(a, d, s, c2)
    self.OrGate(c1, c2, c_out)      

    return 'ok'

def RippleCarryAdder_5_bits(self, x_array, y_array, s_array ):

    ############# YOUR CODE HERE ###############

    return 'ok'  

def RippleCarryAdder(self, x_arr, y_arr, s_arr):

    ############ YOUR CODE HERE ############

    return 'ok'
```

Answer (score 1):

The five bit adder should be pretty easy, you just stick together one half adder and 4 full adders:

```
def RippleCarryAdder_5_bits(self, x_array, y_array, s_array ):
    # internal wires
    c0 = self.Wire()
    c1 = self.Wire()
    c2 = self.Wire()
    c3 = self.Wire()

    self.HalfAdder(x_array[0], y_array[0], s_array[0], c0)
    self.FullAdder(x_array[1], y_array[1], c0, s_array[1], c1)
    self.FullAdder(x_array[2], y_array[2], c1, s_array[2], c2)
    self.FullAdder(x_array[3], y_array[3], c2, s_array[3], c3)
    self.FullAdder(x_array[4], y_array[4], c3, s_array[4], s_array[5])

    return 'ok'
```

The unlimited-size version is essentially the same, you just use a loop to let you handle an unlimited number of bits, rather than hard coding a specific number:

```
def RippleCarryAdder(self, x_arr, y_arr, s_arr):
    # handle first bit manually
    carry_out = self.Wire()
    self.HalfAdder(x_array[0], y_array[0], s_array[0], carry_out)

    # handle all middle bits with a loop
    for x, y, s in zip(x_arr[1:-1], y_arr[1:-1], s_arr[1:-2]):
        carry_in = carry_out
        carry_out = self.Wire()
        self.FullAdder(x, y, carry_in, s, carry_out)

    # handle last bit manually too
    self.FullAdder(x_array[-1], y_array[-1], carry_out, s_array[-2], s_array[-1])

    return 'ok'
```

You could probably make the logic simpler if you wanted too. You could use the loop for all the bits if you could pass in an always zero `carry_in` wire to the first one, and if there was an easy way to connect the final `carry_out` to connect to `s_array[-1]` (I guess an `OrGate` with the same input twice could work for the latter).